# Erro com o ChromeDriver.exe ao utilizar o Coypu for Selenium

Tags: c#, framework, testes-de-unidade, visual-studio-2015

Estou fazendo uma app, para testar esse *framework* de teste unitário. Porém, ele indica um erro que não consegue encontrar o caminho onde estar o ChromeDriver.exe, sendo que, o mesmo se encontra na pasta que indiquei.

Aqui segue meu código:

```
using System;
using Coypu;
using Coypu.Drivers;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace Coybu
{
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        //Aqui indico o caminho onde se encontra o GoogleDrive.exe
        IWebDriver drive = new ChromeDriver("C:/Google");

        var sessionConfig = new SessionConfiguration()
        {
            Browser = Browser.Chrome,
            AppHost = "minhaurl.com",
            Driver = typeof(Coypu.Drivers.Selenium.SeleniumWebDriver)
    };

        var browser = new BrowserSession(sessionConfig);


        browser.Visit("/usuario/login");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Tente dar um Clean e Depois um Build, Isso ajuda a atualizar o app tirando as falhas, Muitas vezes o codigo está correto e fica ocorrendo um erro bug e após dar um build ele atualiza e volta a funcionar normalmente. Dá um Build e vê se resolve.

Comment: Continua com o mesmo erro

Comment: O nome que você está setando é o nome que está o corretamente o exe? Tente tirar do diretório C e coloque em uma pasta por exemplo a pasta usuários e seta e veja se consegue achar o arquivo.

Comment: Já fiz isso. Ele carrega o GoogleDrive.exe na pasta que eu indiquei, porém aparece esse erro.